# Delete Comment popup

Tags: javascript, php, popup

I'm wanting to popup a confirm/cancel div in which I can style when my users click the delete button in my feed. But what I have isn't working. And I'm wondering if its because I don't have anything in delete.php to tell it to direct it into a popup. It just goes to the delete.php page atm. Could someone give me some direction please?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function confirmDelete(){
var agree=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");
if (agree)
     return true ;
else
     return false ;
}
</script>
```

Button:

```
 echo '<a href="mysite/raw/sn-extend/theme/default/delete.php?id='.$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].'" onClick="confirmDelete(); alt="Delete" title="Delete" class="delete">X</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

Comment: Why doesn't `confirmDelete` just `return confirm(...);`?

Comment: I'm not sure, do I have to add the link in between the onClick="confirmDelet(MY_LINK); ?

Comment: Perhaps just a typo in the question, but you're missing a " after onClick="confirmDelete() in the string you're echoing to create the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to `return` the value returned by `confirmDelete`.
- The attribute is `onclick`, not `onClick`.
- The attribute is missing a closing quote.

#### JavaScript

```
function confirmDelete(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");
}
```

#### PHP

```
echo '<a ... onclick="return confirmDelete();" ...';
```

---

That said, it looks like you're using jQuery (albeit a super old version). If that's really the case, **use jQuery** and start writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) already.

```
$(function ()
{
    $('a.delete').click(confirmDelete);
});
```

Get yourself a reasonably recent version of jQuery as well.

Comment: I'm putting this in the php file right? Or does it 'have' to be in the html file?

Comment: I don't understand the question. PHP generates HTML. The jQuery snippet I posted is JavaScript, which is neither PHP nor HTML.

Comment: You state the attribute is missing a closing quote, when I add this it throws me a red error next to the return true; because the closing quote is at the end I believe.

Comment: You can add the javascipt at the top of both php and html pages right?

Answer (score 1):

This doens't regards jQuery but anyway you could do in this way:

```
<script>
function confirmDelete(idPassed){

  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?"))
    window.location = "mysite/raw/sn-extend/theme/default/delete.php?id=" + idPassed;

 }
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="confirmDelete('<?php echo $streamitem_data['streamitem_id']; ?>');" alt="Delete" title="Delete" class="delete">X</a>
```